# Node JS API Sequelize PostgreSQL UUID as primary key return error "column Nan does not exist"

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I'm working on a REST API for the backend of a simple e-commerce app using **Node JS**, **PostgreSQL** and **Sequelize**, and I'm facing an issue with Sequelize when I try to add a product to the shopping cart. It returns an error `"column Nan does not exist"` 
Initially I was using Integer for the user Id as the primary key, then I changed for **UUID** to better suit the purpose.
The code I'm using for the models and migrations is the following:

```
//User model
export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define(
    'User',
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        unique: true,
      },
      name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: {
          name: 'user_email',
          msg: 'A user with this email already exists.'
        }
      },
    },
  User.associate = models => {
    User.hasOne(models.Cart, {
      foreignKey: 'userId',
      as: 'cart',
      onDelete: 'cascade'
    });
  };

  User.associate = models => {
    User.hasMany(models.Order, {
      foreignKey: 'userId',
      as: 'orders',
      onDelete: 'cascade'
    });
  };

  return User;
};

//User migration
export const up = (queryInterface, Sequelize) =>
  queryInterface.createTable('Users', {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    name: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    password: Sequelize.STRING,
    email: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      unique: true
    },
    createdAt: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.fn('now')
    },
    updatedAt: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.fn('now')
    },
  });

export const down = queryInterface => queryInterface.dropTable('Users');
```

Cart model

```
export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Cart = sequelize.define('Cart', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    userId: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      allowNull: false
    },
    cartItem: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false,
      get(value) {
        return JSON.parse(this.getDataValue(value));
      },
      set(value) {
        this.setDataValue('cartItem', JSON.stringify(value));
      }
    }
  });

  Cart.associate = models => {
    Cart.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: 'userId',
      as: 'owner'
    });
  };
  return Cart;
};
```

Cart migration

```
export const up = (queryInterface, Sequelize) =>
  queryInterface.createTable('Carts', {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
    },
    userId: {
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
      allowNull: false
    },
    cartItem: {
      type: Sequelize.TEXT,
      allowNull: false
    },
    createdAt: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.fn('now')
    },
    updatedAt: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.fn('now')
    }
  });

export const down = queryInterface => queryInterface.dropTable('Carts');
```

Code to handle the add to cart:

```
addToCart() {
    return this.asyncWrapper(async (req, res) => {
      const { body, user } = req;

      body.userId = user.id;
      const cart = await this.service.addToCart(body);

      this.sendResponse(res, cart, undefined, 201);
    });
  }
```

Add to cart service

```
async cart(userId, options = {}) {
    const cart = await super.find({ userId }, options);
    return cart;
  }

  async addToCart(data, options) {
    const { userId, productId, qty } = data;

    const [result] = await this.model.findOrCreate({
      where: { userId: +userId },
      defaults: { cartItem: new CartItem() }
    });

    const cartData = JSON.parse(result.dataValues.cartItem);
    const cartItem = new CartItem(cartData);

    const product = await ProductService.getById(productId, { plain: true });

    ExceptionHandler.throwErrorIfNull(product);

    const cart = cartItem.addToCart(product, qty);

    result.cartItem = cart;
    result.save();

    return result;
  }
```

The SQL query generated by Sequelize is the following:
`SELECT "id","userId","cartItem","createdAt","updatedAt" FROM "Carts" AS "Cart" WHERE "Cart"."userId" = NaN LIMIT 1;`

The goal is to use **UUID** as primary key in the database.
This issue started when I changed the Datatype from Integer for UUID and I can't see what is wrong with the code.

Any advice on how to solve this?

```
Sequelize version: "^5.21.9" with "pg": "^8.2.0" and "pg-hstore": "^2.3.3".
```

Comment: Can you share your model code, and the code that's passing the userId into the query?

Comment: @Noah The model code is the Cart mode that is already in the post.  The code to handle the query is the following: `addToCart() {
    return this.asyncWrapper(async (req, res) => {
      const { body, user } = req;

      body.userId = user.id;
      const cart = await this.service.addToCart(body);

      this.sendResponse(res, cart, undefined, 201);
    });
  }`

Comment: show `this.service.addToCart` code. And please add it to your post and not as a comment here

Comment: Also you don't need to indicate `unique` and `defaultValue` options in PK field in `User` model because it's already a primary key (that means unique) and its default value is generated by DB. Also you need to indicate `autoIncrement: true` in PK field in model so Sequelize knows that a default value whould be generated by DB

Comment: @Anatoly `autoIncrement: true` doesn't work since I'm using UUID identifier

Comment: It works because it means that a DB should generate a default value and not a Sequelize itself. That's why you shouldn't indicate `defaultValue` in a model field. Usually I set default value in a migration as `defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('uuid_generate_v4()')`

Comment: @Anatoly I tried `defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('uuid_generate_v4()')` in the migration files, but after I run `npm run db:migrate` it returns an error `function uuid_generate_v4() does not exist` . Do I need to import something?

Comment: Yes, you nedd to add an extension `uuid-ossp`: `CREATE EXTENSION uuid-ossp
 SCHEMA "public"
 VERSION 1.1`

Comment: @Anatoly Unfortunately adding the `uuid-ossp` extension in the PostgreSQL database and using the `defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('uuid_generate_v4()')` didn't solve the problem. I keep getting `column Nan does not exist` with the generated query `SELECT "id", "userId", "cartItem", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "Carts" AS "Cart" WHERE "Cart"."userId" = NaN`

Comment: I ddin't say it solves `column Nan does not exist`. It solves problems with PK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you switched a data type from `INTEGER` to `UUID` you shouldn't try to convert UUID-string to a number doing `where: { userId: +userId }`.

Pass `userId` as is:

```
where: { userId }
```

Comment: It worked ! Thank you! It was a silly mistake from my part, I totally forgot to change this conversion. Now it's working fine.